# Some questions about git merge

Tags: git

After `git fetch` and `git merge`, I notice the there would be a special entry called `Merge` for the merge commit in `git log`.

For example,

```
commit COMMITID (HEAD -> localBranchName)
Merge: XXXXXXXXXX YYYYYYYYYYY
Author: XXX
Date:   XXXXXXX
Merge remote tracking branch into ....
```

How should I interpret `Merge` in above commit log?

Another question followed by this `git merge` is that after this git merge, I saw below history from `git log`:

`The merge commit to bring remote changes`

`The new feature commit in the local branch`

`The commit since the first checkout`

If I issue `git push`, is git smart enough to know it just need to push `The new feature commit in the local branch` to remote? If not, what is the correct way to do achieve this goal? (My new feature commit does not have any conflict with the remote changes brought by the `git merge`, and I just worry the commit brought `git merge` would also show up in the history of remote).

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an *entry;* it's a *description*.

When you run `git merge`, Git can<sup>1</sup> make a commit that differs in one particular way from most ordinary commits.  Most ordinary commits store the raw hash ID of a single *parent* commit.  This parent is the immediate predecessor of this one commit.  What makes a merge commit special is that it stores the hash ID of at least two (and usually exactly two) parent commits.

Remember that Git is not about *files*, and not about *branches* either, really.  What Git is really about is *commits*.  Commits store, as their primary data, snapshots—a frozen copy of *each* of your files, as of the state it had when you made that one particular commit—plus some metadata, including who made the commit (name and email address), when (date and time stamp), and why (log message).  There's one more key item, which is the commit's *parent or parents*, in every commit, and the metadata format is flexible and can accommodate extra information, such as the log-message's text encoding (Git assumes UTF-8 if you don't specify it).

Each commit has its own unique hash ID.  No other commit can have *that* hash ID: once it's been assigned to *that* commit, it means *that* commit—forever, or at least as long as the commit continues to exist.  Moreover, this hash ID is universal: *every* Git agrees that *that* commit has *that* hash ID.

A branch name, in Git, just holds the raw hash ID of one commit.  By definition, this one commit is the *tip* of the branch.  But this one commit holds the hash ID of its parent commit, i.e., the commit that *was* the tip of the branch at some point earlier.  That parent holds the hash ID of *its* parent, was the tip of the commit before that, and so on.

When your run `git log`, it starts from the current commit—which is usually the tip of a branch, because you are "on" a branch as `git status` will say—and shows you that commit.  Then it moves back one step to that commit's parent, and shows the parent commit.  Then it moves back another step, and so on:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Here, we are on branch `master`.  The name `master` holds the real hash ID (whatever it is—some big ugly string of letters and numbers) of commit `H`, which is the *last* commit in the branch.  Commit `H` holds the hash ID of its parent `G`.  We say that `master` *points to* `H`, and `H` points to `G`.  `G` of course holds another parent hash, so `G` points to `F`, which points back to another earlier commit, and so on.

Running `git log` will show commit `H`, then `G`, then `F`, and so on.

A merge commit has two parents:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

Here, `git log` will show `N`, then `M`, and then—well, now it has a problem.  It will note that `M` is a *merge* commit and has two parents, and give you shortened versions of the hash IDs of *both* `J` and `L`.  Then it will move on to show you one of `J` or `L`.  Then it will move on to show you one of `I` or `K` or the other of the two it didn't show you yet.  Then it will move on again—eventually it shows you all of the `I-J` and `K-L` forks of history—and shows `H`, and `G`, and so on.

The exact order of visiting commits with `git log`, when it comes across merge commits like this, is something you can control, to some extent, using `--date-order`, `--author-date-order`, or `--topo-order`.  But the best way to view this stuff is with `git log --graph` or a graphical viewer, which not only shows the commits, but also their connections.

Note that these commits *are* the history in your repository.  In Git, commits are history; history is nothing but commits (or some selected subset of them).

> If I issue `git push`, is git smart enough to know it just need to push The new feature commit in the local branch to remote?

The main thing you need to know is that `git push` sends *commits*, and then has to ask the other Git to set some *name* by which people can find the commits.  So when you run `git push`, you select two things:

- a specific commit on your side, such as the one named by your current branch, and
- a name that the *other* Git—the one you're sending commits to—should set.

You can just run `git push origin master`, or `git push` with no more arguments at all to let Git use your default branch—whatever it is—to specify both of these.  Git will find the tip commit of the branch—the one whose hash ID is in the branch name on your side—and send that commit to the other Git.

The commit your Git just sent has a parent hash ID inside it—or in this case, since it's a merge commit, *two* parent hash IDs.  That other Git can tell, right away, whether it has the parent commits.  If not, it asks your Git for those too.  If so, it's done.  If it needs another commit or two, it gets them and checks *their* parent IDs, and gets *those* commits if it needs them, and so on.

The result is that after your `git push`, your Git has sent not only the one specific commit you named, but also *all history needed to lead up to that commit*.  Then their Git inspects the request, which in this case, is to set *their* branch name to match yours.  If they think that's OK, they'll accept your push.  If not, they'll reject it.

The end result of a successful push by branch name—`git push origin master` or similar—is that their `master` now matches your `master`: it stores the same raw commit hash ID, and from that hash ID, both Gits will find the same set of commits.  Both Gits now contain the same history.

---

<sup>1</sup>We must use the word *can* here, rather than *does*, because while `git merge` has a job described as "merging", there are a bunch of ways that it can either fail entirely, or do the job without actually merging anything.  You made a merge that required doing real work, so it did, and made a merge commit as a result.

Comment: if I `git push <remotename> <commit SHA>:<remotebranchname>` for a specific commit, the merge commit automatically generated by Git would not also get push to the remote? Is that correct?

Comment: If you use a commit hash, you'll call up that Git, ask them if they have that commit, and if not, send them that commit (and all earlier commits if/when necessary), then ask their Git to set their branch name to point to that commit hash. If you pick a commit that's "before" the merge, or unrelated to it, that would indeed not send the merge. If you make commits that come "after" the merge (so that the merge is an ancestor of the new commits) and push one of those, that would send the merge, and both legs of the merge if needed.